Are these IFR Pattern colors following a standard?
I recently came across a series of IFR practice patterns such as the example below that use red for descent and blue for climbs.
Are these colors standard in the IFR world or was it just made up for that document?


Published IFR procedures are always black and white only. But that doesn't stop a person making training material to use colours to good effect, and that seems like a particularly well designed example of a custom training aid.

They don't, but maybe they should. Although, as most are printable from home those without color printers wouldn't get the benefit.

"Always" is a strong word.

@GdD You don't want colours in a dark cockpit. High contrast B&W is it. The place you will see colours is low alt IFR charts where the terrain areas are depicted in light green, but has no practical use. In a dark cockpit you won't be able to make out the green.

NOAA (and probably other government sources) may publish "always" in B&W only, but Jeppesen does use a few shades of brown to depict terrain on their approach charts, and will sometimes use a red-ish color to title certain notes on departure and arrival charts (typically, airspeed restrictions).  In any event, though, what's depicted in the OP looks like somebody's convention for their training aid, and is definitely not anything in widespread use.

@JohnK that is incorrect, as randomhead indicated. USG charts include several shades of brown to indicate terrain or airport hot spots.

Yeah, that was a couple of iterations ago -- we referred to them as "NOS" charts, but that term isn't current either.  So it's just "the FAA" now.  Either way, the underlying point remains, that Jepp does add color to some of their products.

@Timbo Not to the text and track lines, things you must be able to see in a dark or red lit cockpit. The colours vanish or are washed out.

I don't remember any such convention being any sort of widespread standard in aviation generally. Some conventions, like colors in the cockpit (i.e. magenta = target, amber = caution, red = warning) are basically universal; what's shown in the OP is nothing like that.
